# Ruby RSS Module parsing custom tags

Tags: ruby, xml, rss

Using the sample code in the documentation:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html

I am able to get standard items like `item.title` and `item.pubDate`, but not custom tags, for example, if I were parsing an RSS feed of torrent magnet links and the selector was labelled `magnetURI`.

```
script.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `magnetURI' for #<RSS::Rss::Channel::Item:0x007f8452ac6718> (NoMethodError)
```

I'm confident that the issue is that these non-standard tags need to be defined, since I can pull the rest of the data without issue.

Can these be declared using this module? I saw that gems like [these](https://github.com/cardmagic/simple-rss) seem to have that functionality, so it was unclear if the RSS library could do it by default.